# Change Button on Wordpress Site with JS

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, paypal

Following problem, am using PayPal pro forms with s2members. This generates a form with PayPal Button at the end.

I would love to change the button to an own designed button. I tried CSS / JS with elementid but does not work.

[Site with PP Button](http://addictiveleadership.com/membership-account/membership-checkout/)

Is there a way to change it to an other image or is that blocked by PayPal?

Comment: It uses an image, so it's probably not likely you can somehow replace it with your own via CSS, I'm sure PayPal has some branding guidelines you have to follow as well which may come into consideration.

Answer (score 1):

Editing the source URI of an image (or an attribute of any tag) is relatively simple in JavaScript.
You are able to do this using the JavaScript `document.getElementById()` function to get the element with the ID of `s2member-pro-paypal-checkout-submit`, and then use `setAttribute()` to change the `src` attribute to the URI of any image you'd like to use for the button.

Ideally this JavaScript would just have to be run at the `DOMContentLoaded` event.

Comment: That is what i did but beacuse it will be integrated by shortcode or some other way it will not work. Is that possible because of the shortecode it will not work?